# Modify file names in tar file without extracting files to temporary location

Tags: command-line, tar, command

I have a tar file that contains some files in a folder named `old_name`. Now I'd like to create a new tar file where that folder has been renamed to `new_name` without extracting to file to disk as that would be significantly slower for large archives (More than double the disk reads and writes).
I know how to do that: `tar -xf old.tar; tar -cf new.tar --transform 's/old_name/new_name/' old_name`

I've tried a few things but none seemed to work:

- `tar -cOf old.tar | tar -xf new.tar --transform 's/old_name/new_name/'`
- `cat old.tar | tar --delete --transform 's/old_name/new_name/' > new.tar`
- `cat old.tar | tar -u --transform 's/old_name/new_name/' > new.tar`

But nothing seems to work.

Closed I've found are these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/31716185/1996022
- [Efficiently remove file(s) from large .tgz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80239/45867)

But those are about removing files in the tarball, not changing their paths.

Comment: @Quasímodo why does that matter? But in my particular case it’s around 1GB

Comment: You could untar it in shared memory (in my system, `/dev/shm`), so that it is in RAM, not on disk.

Comment: I don’t have that available.

Comment: when creating/extracting there is `--transform s/foo/bar/`, it won't modify your archive file a you wanted. i mention for t anyone who may find it a suitable work around to only apply this rename/fix at extract time

Answer (score 4):

tar can create or extract tar's but it can't operate on streams in this way.

You'll need something like `tar-stream` - it even has an example that does what you are asking:

https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream#modifying-existing-tarballs

Comment: Thank you for showing this project, but NPM is not available on my target systems.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [archivemount](https://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount.html) to mount your archive on a mountpoint, rename your directory, then unmount the archive?

```bsh
$ archivemount archive.tar /mnt/archive

$ ls /mnt/archive
/mnt/archive/archive/file1
/mnt/archive/archive/file2

$ mv /mnt/archive/archive/file2 /mnt/archive/archive/file3

$ ls /mnt/archive
/mnt/archive/archive/file1
/mnt/archive/archive/file3

$ umount /mnt/archive

$ tar -tf archive.tar
archive/file1
archive/file3

# It will move the original archive to archive.tar.orig
$ tar -tf archive.tar.orig
archive/file1
archive/file2
```

I found the tool in this related answer: [How to add/update a file to an existing tar.gz archive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13093/how-to-add-update-a-file-to-an-existing-tar-gz-archive). It also mentions a similar tool `tarfs`.